# Set Fields "Phone 1..8 Selector" via EWS (c#, ExchangeServer)

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I access ExchangeServer with the help of EWS interface (c#) and create new contacts.

Now I want to set over EWS, which telephone number is displayed in the first place, which second and so on. The fields for it should exist, for example I have found the following description:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/standard-fields-overview

*Phone 1 Selector (through Phone 8 Selector)*

How do I access these fields via EWS? How do I define the ExtendedPropertyDefinition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled via the PidLidContactItemData property which is documented https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765809.aspx . I would suggest you look at the property value (and what changes) when you make modifications in Outlook, the extended prop would look something like

```
 ExtendedPropertyDefinition prop = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Address, 0x8007, MapiPropertyType.IntegerArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, so I could set the phone numbers (index = 3..6). Only the settings for the addresses (index = 1) and emails (index = 2) do not work. (Outlook 2013, Exchange Server, 2013)

Comment: If you use a mapi editor like outlook or mfcmapi to look at the values that change when you make changes in outlook that should point you in the right direction